# How to upload multiple files via Html form object with just one input field

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-apps-script

I have created a Html form with file input field and multiple attribute activated

```
<input type="file" name="documents" multiple size="11">
```

This is the function that submits the form object to client side function

```
<script>
    function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
                var div = document.getElementById('output');
                var docs = document.getElementById('myFile');
                var firstName = document.getElementById('first').value;
                var lastName = document.getElementById('last').value;
                var hid = document.getElementById("hidden");

                for(i=0;i< docs.files.length ; i++){
                    div.innerHTML = hid+hid.file+"<h3>Please do not refresh or close the page. Your files are uploading...</h3>";
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(update).uploadFile(formObject);
                    docs
                }
</script>
```

This is the client side function implemented

```
function uploadFile(formObject) {
  Logger.log("called");
  var firstName=formObject.firstName;
  var lastName=formObject.lastName;
  var file = formObject.documents;
  Logger.log(file);
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var folder,url;
  if(root.getFoldersByName("Application Documents - Clients").hasNext()){
    folder = root.getFoldersByName("Application Documents - Clients").next();
  } else{
    folder = root.createFolder("Application Documents - Clients");
  }
  if(folder.getFoldersByName(firstName+" "+lastName).hasNext()){
    url = folder.getFoldersByName(firstName+" "+lastName).next().createFile(file).getUrl();
  } else {
    url = folder.createFolder(firstName+" "+lastName).createFile(file).getUrl();
  }
  return url;
}
```

The output is, I am getting only the first file uploaded thrice if the total file uploads are 3.
Means its just uploading the first file selected at the time of form submission.

I want to get all selected files uploaded to my drive on the same folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're executing this 3 times `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(update).uploadFile(formObject);` so probably you need to pass in something else. `.files` has file objects, probably you can pass in those. It seems like you're treating them as strings thought, by assigning them to `.value` of another input .. that can't be right. Try `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(update).uploadFile(docs.files[i]);`

Comment: I have removed that value line as it was just a hit and try i did but got same results as you told. And, I have tried calling method the way you are telling but google documentation says it all. That we cannot pass the parameter other than Number, Boolean , string , null or form object (if it is the only parameter of the function). https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Comment: I think this might help: https://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files use a FileReader to read the file and pass that. This uses `uploadFileToGoogleDrive` but I imagine it's similar to `uploadFile`.

Comment: Yes, This method also results only one file upload as we can only send one reader object to the app script web app via one html form.

Comment: Can I ask you about the size of files you want to upload? Because, if one file is more than 50 MB, you are required to use the resumable upload. If the total size of several files you want to upload in one time is less than 50 MB, you can send them to GAS side at once without using for loop.

Comment: Tried the files less then 50 MB too. Normally files will be less then 50 MB in total. I guess this problem is nothing related to file size. Its relate to fetching the file array into the app script. The thing happening is due to single input field app script is converting first file uploaded to blob. If any how there is a way to get multiple blobs into the app script via form object element then it will be sorted